# Distance transform of grayscale image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, distance

Matlab has `bwdist` and `graydist`: I was looking for something like `bwdist` for grayscale images, but I wasn't sure what the mask specified in `graydist` was.

When I'm working with the `graydist` function, I have tried:

```
T = graydist(image,image<=0)

T = graydist(image,image<=254)
```

I can't find an example of it being used other than that one Matlab page, but they're using different input arguments. An explanation or suggestions as to how to get the distance transform of a greyscale image in Matlab would be really helpful!

Comment: The mask seems to allow you to specify multiple seeds, correct?

Comment: @beaker Yes it does. I'm not sure what seeds represent in this case though--are they calibrating what's considered an edge in the image?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Octave and `graydist` hasn't been implemented so I can't try it out. I would simply be guessing based on the algorithm at the bottom of the MATLAB documentation page.